# C++: vector size is wrong and higher than the number of elements

Tags: c++, opengl, vector

In my attempt to load `.OBJ`-files I load vertex data into `std::vectors` to send them to the GPU later. I fill three vectors, for normals, vertices and texture coordinates. The size of the normal vector is far higher than the size of the other two vectors, even if its filled with the same number of elements.

Code:

```
SceneTree* generateSceneTree(OBJScene* scene){
    PostProcessing::triangulateFaces(scene);
    SceneNode* node = new SceneNode;

    vector<Vec<3>>& sceneNormals = scene->attributeData[Attribute::Normal];
    vector<Vec<3>>& sceneVertices = scene->attributeData[Attribute::Position];
    vector<Vec<3>>& sceneTexCoords = scene->attributeData[Attribute::TexCoord];

    map<string,MaterialInfo*> mtls;
    for(string s : scene->mtlLibs){
        auto temp = loadMTL(s);
        mtls.insert(temp.begin(),temp.end());
    }

    vector<Vec<3>> meshNormals;      <-- creating vectors here.
    vector<Vec<3>> meshVertices;
    vector<Vec<2>> meshTexCoords;
    for(auto g : scene->groups){
        meshNormals.clear();
            meshNormals.reserve(g.faces.size()*3);
        meshVertices.clear();
            meshVertices.reserve(g.faces.size()*3);
        meshTexCoords.clear();
            meshTexCoords.reserve(g.faces.size()*3);
        AABB bBox;
        cout << "num of faces: " << g.faces.size() << endl;
        for(auto f : g.faces){
            for(auto p : f.points){
                uint vIndex = p.indices[Attribute::Position];
                uint nIndex = p.indices[Attribute::Normal];
                uint tIndex = p.indices[Attribute::TexCoord];

                Vec<3> n = sceneNormals.at(nIndex);
                Vec<3> v = sceneVertices.at(vIndex);
                Vec<3> t = sceneTexCoords.at(tIndex);

                meshNormals.push_back(n);
                meshVertices.push_back(v);
                meshTexCoords.push_back(t.toVec<2>());

                bBox += meshVertices.back();
            }
        }
        cout << "meshNormals size: " << meshNormals.size() << endl;
        cout << "meshVertices size: " << meshVertices.size() << endl;
        cout << "meshTexCoords size: " << meshTexCoords.size() << endl;
        Mesh* m = new Mesh({
            {meshVertices,Attribute::Position},
            {meshNormals,Attribute::Normal},
            {meshTexCoords,Attribute::TexCoord}
        },GL_TRIANGLES);
        SceneLeaf* leaf = new SceneLeaf;
        leaf->nodeData = {Matrix4(),bBox};
        leaf->leafData = {m, mtls[g.mtlName]};
        node->addChild(leaf);
    }
    return node;
}
```

Output:

```
num of faces: 1087474
meshNormals size: 2958875950
meshVertices size: 3262422
meshTexCoords size: 3262422
```

This seems highly illogical. The program crashs afterwards with a `std::bad_array_new_length` exception because the `Mesh` class cant create an array of size `2958875950` to send to the GPU.

**Update:**

If I swap the declarations of `meshVertices` and `meshNormals`, `meshVertices` has the wrong size. So the first created vector is affected.

If I use `std::list` instead of `std::vector`, everything works.

If I comment out the `....reserve(g.faces.size()*3);` lines, a `std::bad_alloc` is thrown.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://www,sscce.org).

Comment: Comment out the other vector's that you're calling `push_back` on.  If the number is then correct, then the issue is likely a memory overwrite or similar bug.

Comment: Ill try that, I already tried some stuff, updating the quesion now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have a memory corruption bug "somewhere" that is overwriting the `meshNormals` variable on the stack. The fact that swapping the `meshNormals` and `meshVertices` declarations leads to `meshVertices` becoming bad matches that theory.

To narrow in on the problem you can do a few things:

1. Comment out all lines in the inner `for(auto p : f.points)` loop and see if the error still occurs.
2. Assuming it doesn't, start uncommenting lines one-by-one until the error shows up again.
3. Try making a minimal, stand-alone test code example that duplicates the problem (it would help immensely if you did this before posting a SO question).

Comment: You were right. `t.toVec<2>()` was the error. The function had a bug, that wrote over the end of the new Vec<2> that it created. This way i accidentally destroyed the size infomartion of the `std::vector` that lies behind it in the memory. Well, typicial c array madness :D I should have used boundary checks from the start.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that your pointers at the start are pointing to somewhere else, either:

1. You are casting the "scene" structure.
2. You have junk or unset pointer in the scene structure for normal vector. Could be that you put junk there far before entring the function.

You did notice the 2958875950 is junk/negative integer?

Comment: I dont think that either the scene structure or normal data is the problem. I noticed, that the first `vector` declaration is always the one with the wrong size. If i swap the declaration of `meshVertices` and `meshNormals`, `meshVertices` has the junk size.

Comment: so it could be that you are referencing a different type instead of scene direct class to the function?

Comment: i found the error. you can read it in the comment of the accepted answer.